Where to put a 300Ω to 75Ω balun
Just bought a house with two old-style antennas in the attic.  Standard 300Ω flat cable going down to wall plugins.  These plugins are not in convenient places, so I want to run a new line from each to F connectors to work with today's TVs.
Which is better, to run more flat cable and put the balun at the end, or put the balun at the current plug and run RG6 from there?

Surely you mean F connector, not BNC..?

... and 75 ohm coax (RG-59 or RG-6), not 50 ohm.

It's been so long (1984) since I switched from electronics to software, I couldn't tell the difference by eye. No matter, since neither cable nor balun is marketed by that—both just say "TV" – but I edited accordingly.

Cool question. Glad you asked it.

If you can have flat cable in free space, away from anything metallic (at least one or two wire spacing's distance, say?), it will be better over the distance: lower losses.  Small pieces of metal are fine, like a nail or staple to hold the cable to the wall.
If it has to run along framing, other cables, etc., the nearby metal will disturb the fields of the twin-lead, and coax may be better in that case.  That is, nearby metal will introduce loss itself (through a combination of mismatch, coupling and reflection, not necessarily by absorptive loss exactly; thus the real story is more complicated, and varies from channel to channel), and while the coax has higher loss per length, it is fully shielded from such effects and can be ran in any environment, including ductwork, conduit, etc. (Local regulations apply, of course).
Indeed, a balun always goes between coax and twin-lead, whether it's at the receiver, antenna, or anywhere inbetween.  It can be placed in-line just fine.

In addition to disturbed impedance due to nearby metal, nearby electrical noise will also readily couple to the flat cable.

So the further upstream the better for the balun.  Running the RG6 down the walls isn't practical, but I'll put the balun in the old box (more room) and run RG6 in the crawl space to the new locations.

One thing you might consider is running coax all the way and using a power over coax amplifier. This is an amplifier that you can put right at the antenna while the power supply for it goes at the TV end. This puts the amplifier before the cable where the signal is going to be strongest and noise lowest and the power supply where it's easiest to find an outlet.
You'd want to replace the twin lead with coax, otherwise you'd have to put the amp where the twin lead and coax meet, so you'd have any loss and noise from the twin lead before the amp which is not optimal.
Unless you live in an area where over the air TV signals are reasonably strong an amplifier is almost a necessity. I've set up OTA antennas where I just used a loop of wire and a balun, and an amplifier makes a big difference. It should also give you a strong enough signal that you can use a splitter to feed multiple sets.

Unfortunately, running coax all the way isn't an option.  Most of our channels are strong.  Once, I found a twenty foot bit of leftover cable, broke the shield on the plug end and got a clear picture with that.
